# can someone help me find what happened to my eth

Tags: ether

I transferred some eth to my account from a trading platform and it shows transaction complete but there is an additional transaction which i didnt make which transfered my funds to an unknown address
0x8F8A1f9A6ba8ccbfebA7e3DA5ee6a4CFC82dCF2E this is my address
https://etherscan.io/address/0x8f8a1f9a6ba8ccbfeba7e3da5ee6a4cfc82dcf2e
the first 3 transactions were mine but i didnt make the last
the funds never showed up in my wallet either or someone drained it the second it arrived but i dont know how

Comment: If u didn’t make the last transact, then someone has your private key or seed. what are u using ? Mobile wallet or MEW or metamask? Don’t use it anymore, probably better to don’t use the device either

Comment: im using metamask on my pc

Comment: How did you generate the private key/wallet you've used in Metamask? Have you been using Ganache for testing, then imported that account into Metamask (e.g. using the mnemonic), and switched over to main net?

Comment: thats what i did yeah

Comment: It used to be the case (and probably still is) that private keys created in Ganache could be generated deterministically, and therefore are all publicly known. It sounds like one of the bots who watch all the associated known addresses - and who know all the Ganache private keys - grabbed your funds as soon as you sent them there.

Comment: this helped a lot ty

Comment: Just checking a bit more, it looks like the seeds _are_ randomly generated (or perhaps pseudo-randomly generated), but are not guaranteed to be secure. There's a warning from Truffle when you create an address: "_This mnemonic was created for you by Truffle. It is not secure._" Seems a bit silly, because I'm sure lots of people must have lost funds in the same way as you :-\

Comment: then il consider myself lucky it was just 82 usd

Comment: yes very lucky :D